# Color the boxplot according to their mean value with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Let's consider a boxplot with ggplot:

```
 p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
```

I want the boxes to be filled with a plain color that depends on the mean value of the mpg, for instance from blue to red. I have played with the various group and fill arguments but using "mean(mpg)" always returned the global mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (to fill the boxes with rounded mean values of each cyl group):

```
mtcars$mean <- as.factor(round(ave(mtcars$mpg, as.factor(mtcars$cyl), FUN=mean)))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, fill=mean)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could create a new column that would then be used for the fill.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars%>%
  group_by(cyl)%>%
  mutate(mean_cyl=mean(mpg))%>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl),mpg))+geom_boxplot(aes(fill=mean_cyl))+scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high = "red")
```

Comment: Does your plot show different colors? I can only see 1 value for the mean where running your example